# How to Select data from db2 for current date

Tags: db2

I have to retrieve data from DB2 for current date, but I am not able to find correct solution for the same.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = current-date
```

(I know this is wrong, it's just an example.)

I need a correct where condition for DB2.

Comment: The standard name is `current_date`, you could also use `current date`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two way to get this:

1. There is a special system table 
   [enter link description here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html)

   `SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1`

So you would need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE date = (SELECT current date FROM sysibm.sysdummy1)
```

2. There is even a special register 
   [enter link description here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005870.html)

This allows to avoid the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = CURRENT DATE
```

Comment: The subquery is not necessary, as @mustaccion said: SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE date = current date.

Comment: "There is even a special register" – what do you think you are using in the subquery version?!

Comment: Just added it for completeness. Would not really use it ;)